# why are my new and create actions not working with accepts_nested_attributes_for with has_many through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through, has-many

I'm building a rail 3.2.16 app using 3 models related with a has_many through association but my saving actions are not working. this are my models:

```
class Cliente < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :prestamos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :prestamos, reject_if: :all_blank
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prestamos
  has_many :clientes, :through => :prestamos
end

class Prestamo < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_numericality_of :monto, only_integer: true
  validates :monto, presence: true
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :cliente, inverse_of: :prestamos
end
```

When I try to build my @cliente in clientes_controller#new with this

```
@cliente = current_user.clientes.build
```

and this in #create

```
@cliente = current_user.clientes.build(params[:cliente])
```

and using this view

```
<%= simple_form_for(@cliente) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :nombre %>
  <%= f.input :cedula %>
  <%= f.input :direccion %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :prestamos do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.input :monto %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

The render HTML is the expected one, but on save I got the validations errors related to monto in prestamo model. By the way, the monto field is displayed twice.

The erros I having:

Prestamos monto is not a number
Prestamos monto can't be blank

I really hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you whitelisting (using `attr_accessible`) `prestamos_attributes` in the `User` model?

Comment: No, I just added it to my Cliente Model. by the way, I just added it to test it but the errors remains.

Comment: Would you please add the error message to the question?

Comment: I just added it. Are validation errors, presence and number

Comment: What values are you using that yielded these errors?

Comment: monto is amount in Spanish, so I'm writing a number like 100000 without dot (.) or comma (,).

Comment: @AhmadSherif I could solve it but, I don't know if this is best way, Would you mind check it out, please?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I could solve it, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it since I'm pretty new in Rails (3 month). This is what I did:

First, I changed my join model Prestamo to this:

```
class Prestamo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :monto, :user_id, :cliente_id

  validates_numericality_of :monto, only_integer: true
  validates :monto, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :cliente, inverse_of: :prestamos

end
```

The validation were there already, I just added `:user_id` to the `attr_accessible`.

2nd, I changed my new and create actions to this:

new:

```
def new
  @cliente = Cliente.new
  @cliente.prestamos.build(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

create:

```
@cliente = Cliente.new(params[:cliente])
```

Finally, I added a hidden field to my form just to store the user_id

```
<%= form.simple_fields_for :prestamos do |f| %>
<%= f.input :monto %>
<%= f.input :user_id, as: :hidden %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Looks good so far, except for one thing: storing `user_id` in a hidden input. Don't do that, because the value can be tampered by a malicious user leading to a security issue. Simply remove the hidden input and use this line in the create method: `@cliente = Cliente.new(params[:cliente].merge({user_id: current_user.id}))` and you're done.

Comment: Not working. Can't mass assign user_id. This is the submited form: "cliente"=>{"nombre"=>"Name", "cedula"=>"4568213", "direccion"=>"Arabia", "prestamos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"monto"=>"00000"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Cliente"}

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Use this instead: `@cliente = Cliente.new(params[:cliente]); @cliente.prestamos.each { |p| p.user = current_user }`.

Comment: Now that I think about your approach, I think you shouldn't let the ClientesController handle the creation of the "prestamos", instead, create a LoansController and handle the creation there. Make it nested in the clientes resource. This will let you write it a much cleaner code like this: `@loan = @cliente.loans.create(params[:loan].merge(user: current_user))`

Comment: I already have a controler for prestamos. You mean i shoyld pass the accept_nested_attributes_for to the Prestamo model?

Comment: I mean that the form should submit to the create action of the Prestamos controller, handling creation from there like I mentioned. You won't need `accept_nested_attributes_for` on Prestamo model as you 're creating them directly, not through the Cliente model.